# Possibility for PDOStatement::fetch() method to throw a PDOException

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch, fetch

Is it possible for `PDOStatement::fetch()` to throw an exception *(PDOException)* or only `$dbh->prepare($query)->execute()` could emit an error?

If `PDOStatement::fetch()` won't throw an error, then I can trustingly use it without put it in the `try...catch` clause

Comment: You don't have to put every method that *may* throw an exception into `try..catch`, you know? That only helps if you *expect* an error and know what to do if you caught one. If you don't know what to do when an *exception* occurs, which means an *exceptional, unforeseen problem*, then you may as well let your program die.

Comment: (From docs) The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.

Comment: Based [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), it will return false for all fetch type if failed. So there is no problem even if you didn't put in a `try..catch`, just handle the returned value properly

Comment: @deceze I have a common error handler has to be invoked, which will put error detail information into the log. So I can't just let it die.

Comment: Then that handler should be a global exception handler, no? You don't need to wrap each individual call into `try..catch`.

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko I know this method will return a FALSE when failed to fetch. I just wonder if there exists occasions for this method to throw an error? Or no error for ever, just returning a FALSE? (which is what I hope.)

Comment: check out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) regarding general PDO and error handling. [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) doesn't have an **Errors/Exceptions** section in the documentation so it won't throw one (see [PDO::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) as an example of what to expect if an error will be thrown)

Comment: @WeeZel Thank you very much!! Even if the remote server is disconnected during the loop of fetching, it won't throw an error, just returning a FALSE? Then I'll have another question - how can I know if there's something unusual happened or it just reached the end of the table?

Comment: @Benson I just ran a quick test using PDO on MySQL, ran a simple query on 250 rows then shutdown the mysql daemon during the fetch phase... The fetches continued to succeed. If you're really worried about an exception then keep your `PDO::fetch()` code within a try/catch

Comment: @WeeZel Really really thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WeeZel has provided good answers for this question: [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) doesn't have an Errors/Exceptions section in the documentation so it won't throw one (see [PDO::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) as an example of what to expect if an error will be thrown).

Please refer to the above comments.